# PHP/Mysql Login System

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

at the moment, i'm taking POST information from a form and passing it to a login.php page which runs them through this function:

```
function verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd) {

    $query = "SELECT *
            FROM users
            WHERE username = ? AND password = ?
            LIMIT 1";

    if($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query)) {
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $un, $pwd);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->fetch()) {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

At the moment, the only thing this checks for is whether a matching record exists, which in turn redirects the user to secret.php with this:

```
function validate_user($un, $pwd) {
    $mysql = New Mysql();
    $ensure_credentials = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd);

    if($ensure_credentials) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
        header("location: ../secret.php");
    } else {
        header("location: ../index.php");
    }

}
```

But what i need to do is, instead of one secret page, have a PHP page for each user in the DB (theres only going to be a couple) so i need the function to return the name of the username if successful and redirect them to [username].php and also set a session with the username in it, so on the secret pages i can check whether the right user is coming to the right page? That make sense?

Comment: I get everything but the 'secret' pages, why do you need to create one for each user? why not just use sessions and one 'secret' page?

Comment: see comment on Matt Lowdens answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validate_user($un, $pwd) {
    $mysql = New Mysql();
    $ensure_credentials = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd);

    if($ensure_credentials) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $un;
        header("location: ../secret.php");
    } else {
        header("location: ../index.php");
    }

}
```

*secret.php*

```
<?php
session_start(); //important;

if($_SESSION['status'] != 'authorized') { 
    header("Location: ../index.php");  // not logged in
}

/* user specific stuff.. */
echo '<h1>' . $_SESSION['username'] . '</h1>';

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `user_profile` WHERE `username`="' . $_SESSION['username'] . '"';
//etc
```

**edit**
if you're insisting on having specific pages, have something like this:

inside **ross.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'Ross') { die('you shouldn\'t be here..'); }

// ok it's Ross, carry on
?>
```

probably all better done using DB + sessions

Answer (score 2):

Or, don't pass the username as get parameter, but save the username in the session:

```
if($ensure_credentials) {
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
    $_SESSION['username'] = $un;
    header("location: ../secret.php");
}
```

and in `secret.php`:

```
if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'Jack') {
    echo 'Hey Jack!';
}
elseif ($_SESSION['username'] == 'Jill') {
    echo 'Hello Jill!';
}
else {
    // die / send 404
}
```

or match username against database for custom page content.

Answer (score 1):

I don't discuss about if this is or not a right and clear implementation. I just try to "fix" your code:

```
function validate_user($un, $pwd) {
    $mysql = New Mysql();
    $ensure_credentials = $mysql->verify_Username_and_Pass($un, $pwd);

    if($ensure_credentials) {
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'authorized';
        $_SESSION['username'] = $un;
        header("location: ../{$un}.php");
    } else {
        header("location: ../index.php");
    }

}
```

Into `<username>.php` you can check if  `$_SESSION['username']` is equals to the file name minus the .php extensions

But! Maybe there is a better implementation...for instance instead of having N php files (onece for user) you can have just one php file that will load the right data based on `$_SESSION['username']` value

UPDATED:
At the head of `<username>`.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['status'] == 'authorized' && preg_match("/^{$_SESSION['username']}\\.php$/",__FILE__)){
  echo "OK";!
}else{
  header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a solution that works, i would love to just have one page for all but like i said i'm going to be have varying content on each page.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a page called `member.php` and pass the username as a parameter.

for instance `member.php?username=benhowdle89`.

Would this suffice? What is on the 'secret' page?

If you really need a separate page for each then you could do:

```
if(!is_file($username.'.php')){
    $user_file = fopen($username.'.php', 'w');
    fwrite($user_file, '<p>User content</p>');
}

header('Location:'.$username.'.php', true, 302);
exit;
```

It still doesn't seem like the best solution to the problem. I'd personally just save the user id/name to a session like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = 23;
```

And then I could build the content for each user page dynamically, based on that value.

Comment: I see your point but i'm going to have slightly different content on each page. And its imperative that one user doesnt see another users page. But i cant tell whats going to be on these pages yet, so that why i was going to have one page per user

Answer (score 0):

Redirect them to header secret.php?user=$un

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense and it doable, although I do not see why would you want to do something complicated like that.
First of all you need to return the data from your query instead of true, I do not know what library are you using, although that $stmt->fetch() stuff should return an array, an object, an array of objects, so do something like this $data = $stmt->fetch(); return $data; an put a print_r($data) to see what is inside. Afterwords use the thing with member.php form the aswer above.